# Haskell: How to seed (set the entropy used by) Data.Random?

Tags: haskell, random, random-seed

The random-fu (Data.Random) package in Haskell [offers](https://github.com/mokus0/random-fu/tree/69a563a7b0cf444748e4b38a8bda7ada0b9acf14) the following example:

```
import Data.Random
import System.Random.MWC

logNormal :: Double -> Double -> RVar Double
logNormal mu sigmaSq = do
  x <- normal mu sigmaSq
  return (exp x)

main = do
  mwc <- create
  y <- sampleFrom mwc (logNormal 5 1)
  print y
```

It always generates the same result. I want to seed it from the clock. Ideally without having to get my hands dirty by actually reading the time.

(I haven't seen the word "seed" anywhere in the random-fu documentation, but I have found the phrsae "source of entropy" in a few places.)

Comment: I don't have any firsthand experience with these modules, but at a glance it looks like [`createSystemRandom`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mwc-random-0.14.0.0/docs/System-Random-MWC.html#v:createSystemRandom) might give you an entropy source that's more like what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to seed it from the clock, you can get the time with `getPOSIXTime` . It probably makes more sense to use `createSystemRandom` as Silvio Mayolo suggested.  Both methods are demonstrated in the code below.

```
import Data.Random
import Data.Vector (singleton)
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX (getPOSIXTime)
import System.Random.MWC

logNormal :: Double -> Double -> RVar Double
logNormal mu sigmaSq = do
  x <- normal mu sigmaSq
  return (exp x)

main = do

  t0 <- getPOSIXTime 
  mwc <- initialize (singleton (floor t0))
  y <- sampleFrom mwc (logNormal 5 1)
  print y

  mwc2 <- createSystemRandom
  z <- sampleFrom mwc2 (logNormal 5 1)
  print z
```

Comment: Perfect solution, thank you! Both blocks of `main` will do it; the second is simpler while the first lets you capture the seed to rerun everything.